# How do I craft cactus armor in terraria?

Tags: terraria

I'm a beginner, I just got terraria on xbox 360 and I've heard that I can craft Cactus Armor but have no idea how to do it. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4):

Get 75 pieces of cactus, which are easily found in the desert biome. Use a workbench to craft each piece of the armor set.

Take a look at the [official wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cactus_armor) for more info. It's a great resource when you're trying to learn about the game.

Comment: But it's not showing up?

Comment: @NicholasHunt Do you have a workbench? Are standing next to it? Do you have the cactus in your inventory?

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes and still no cactus armor

Comment: If you give a piece of cactus to the guide, does the armor show up as one of the craftable items? What crafting station does it say?

Comment: How many items are showing as craft-able to you? If it is only 3-4 try clicking on the picture of the hammer and some dots to see a list of everything you can craft in one giant list.

Answer (score 0):

Find the desert biome and swing at cacti with an axe till you get to 75, less with not get you the full suit, and got to work bench and look for the green suit in the crafting area.